# Cocoa Touch Framework class dependencies

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, xcode6

I've got a Cocoa Touch Framework for iOS8 (obviously) with XCode 6.3 that includes both Swift and ObjC classes. This framework is going to be used in a variety of other projects and requires AFNetworking.

Now I could just copy the AFNetworking files into the framework, but in case the other projects require AFNetworking as well (and add AFNetworking as well via source code or CocoaPods), the project will throw warnings because the AFNetworking classes are included in both the framework and the project and the compiler can't device which one to use.

However, if I don't add the AFNetworking files to the framework, I can't use them, obviously.
In my framework development project I've tried to add AFNetworking only to the main project and not the framework, but the framework project still can't find them.
Is there a way to have the framework project reference classes from the project that implements it?

Answer (score 2):

If the framework is a project of yours, enable cocoapods on the framework project, add AFNetworking as a pod dependency on that.
Doing that you should be able to reach AFNetworking classes from both the framework and the main project that uses it.

Comment: Would the main project require a dependency on the AFNetworking pod as well then?

Comment: Are you sure? I mean the main project just includes the .framework file, which by itself doesn't include any AFNetworking files. It just has a dependency on the corresponding pod.

Comment: Nope, not needed. Somehow the .framework file handles that on its own. Thanks a lot SalvoC! Highly appreciate your answer!

Comment: Yes it does, after building the framework you will have all references needed in it

Comment: Actually, this doesn't solve the problem. When I add AFNetworking via CocoaPods to the main project as well (this might need it as well), I still get the duplicate class warnings.

Comment: Aren't you able to use afnetworking without adding it as a dependency of the main project?

Comment: The problem is that the individual frameworks I'm developing all require AFNetworking. The main project that incorporates my frameworks might require AFNetworking as well, though, independently from my frameworks. This main application is actually a customer's project, so I don't have any insight into that. Ideally, I'd like to package my frameworks without AFNetworking so that my customer has to add it to his project as a dependency.

Comment: Ok in this case you could make your library a pod itself and add in its descriptor the dependency to afnetworking. Doing so all the projects tha include it will automatically download the afnetworking pod. You can put it in a private repository of you don't want it to be public. It's a bit tricky but on the long distance you will have done a valuable choice for mantainability.

Comment: Creating a pod isn't really an option I'm afraid. Is there no other way to accomplish this?

Comment: Hey AlBirdie. Please let me know if you figured out how to do this. I'm making a CocoaTouch framework that needs to use AFNetworking, but the people using my framework will probably have AFNetworking already imported, which will cause conflictions like you stated.